# How can I fix paint with orange peel texture?

Tags: paint

I'm working on a new site that is a large penthouse flat. Some amateur painter just put bad quality white emulsion on the walls instead of applying a mist coat. I sanded it down, but the next layer looks really bad. It looks like orange skin in quite a few places! I'm having nightmares that the client will complain, and I will lose my job because of it.

Is there any way I can improve the finish?

A friend of mine told me that alkaline resisting paint could help, but I'm afraid it's too late, since I need to leave the flat in 3 days. I used a really good roller, I did everything like I always do. I suggest the paint (b&q) is not top quality.

Comment: Websearch "paint orange peel" for causes and cures. Nothing much we can do about the last-minute-itis, though, except say "next time, don't do that."

Answer (score 3):

Since you put a layer of emulsion down you basically have to start over with priming and then painting the top coat.  Depending on the thickness of the coat of emulsion I have had to put two coats of primer on.  I would go with the old Killz here (oil based) just to get it done faster.

Comment: Thank you for your answer DMoore! Actually before reading this today I decided to give sand down and put an alkime resistant oil based primer (it was £57 for 5l :( and that was not the dulux). It has a long drying time so I don't know if I have to give another coat, but so far so good it's look nice! Thanks again! Hope other people can learn about this topic!